# Custom styling of com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Tags: android, material-components-android

I am using the new [Google Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) for Android

Currently, I am trying to give a custom look for Tablayout (com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout).

I have created a style as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

However, upon applying this theme, the **tab indicator becomes invisible**.

**Without theme:**

[image]

**With theme:**

[image]

Also, I tried other things like changing tabIndicatorColor and still not working!

How do I fix this? Which is the correct way to change the colors/theme of Material Components?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With these changes, it works as expected:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
     style="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
     app:tabGravity="fill"
     app:tabTextAppearance="@style/customFontStyle">

     //Tab items maybe

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

**Styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I was using android:theme instead of style and that's what caused the issue!

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you should use Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored from [here](https://material.io/components/tabs/android).